# Is there a test framework for Python that supports test dependencies?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm looking for something similar to [JExample](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/jexample), where you can create tests that depend one upon the other. Is there a python testing framework out there that supports this concept?

Comment: Is this for testing Python code (unit testing), or other testing, such as system testing?

Comment: @Keith: I want to use such a framework for testing another system that has a Python interface. In this particular case the test-flow of unittest (and similar) is completely inadequate. For instance, the external system works like a state machine, and the transitions are also time dependent. It would be very awkward to repeat all the previous transitions during a test, hence a I believe a test framework that supports test dependencies will be the best choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried it, but looks like it might interest you:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/proboscis/

Comment: Thank you, this fits the bill. Besides implementing dependencies, it's much more flexible then the setUp->Run->tearDown model of pyunit.The docs mention it is inspired from TestNG, too bad it doesn't seem to have xml/html reporting build in, like TestNG

Comment: Turns out that as proboscis is based on nose, you can use nose's xunit built in plugin to generate an xml report, or you can use it as a starting point to roll your own